# Class 'Ebizmarts_MailChimp_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, class, mailchimp

When I extracted the mailchimp extension in root folder. I came across this error

> Class 'Ebizmarts_MailChimp_Helper_Data' not found in /home/occasion/public_html/occasionwearforkids.com.au/app/Mage.php on line 547

This is my `data.php` file
[image]

And this is my `config` file
[image]

Comment: You can find an answer here on the official forum. https://ebizmarts.com/forums/topics/view/26192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refresh the `Cache` and if `Compilation` is enabled then you just need to disable it from

> Admin > System > Tools > Compilation

If you are not able to open admin then go to the following path and comment some lines which are mentioned below in `config.php`.

> Go to: Magento Root > includes > (open)config.php

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

I hope that'll help you.

Comment: @rehanansari let me know it's work for you or not.?

Comment: i cant i don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset all caches and recompile if enabled.
So try after refreshing cache and disabling compilation from backend.

Comment: i already did that but nothing happened? and how do i disable compilation?

Comment: @rehanansari Admin > System > Tools > Compilation

Comment: i cant open backend i am receiving this error Class 'Ebizmarts_MailChimp_Helper_Data' not found in /home/occasion/public_html/occasionwearforkids.com.au/app/Mage.php on line 547 @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.

Comment: @rehanansari please check my answer for how to disable compilation.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your site compilation is on So follow below solution

**Solution 1:**

Turn Off the compiler from your terminal steps :

1. Open your terminal /connect your ssh access
2. Go to your magento root via this command `cd \yourpathtomagentoDir`
3. Fire this commnad  `php -f compiler.php disable`
4. After this do compile `php -f compiler.php compile`
5. After this enable compile `php -f compiler.php enable`

**Solution 2:**

1. Go to your module's xml file located in `app/etc/modules` and disable the module
2. Clear the cache
3. Now you are able to login in back end
4. Disable the compiler and install your module
5. Do compile and enable your magento compile